# Problems with reading xml after xml serialization

Tags: c#, xml

I want to save a list of objects to xml. Also I'm using gridView to show objects in list. I'm using xml.serialization library. The save from xml is ok and don't have errors. And after I load file, the objects appears in list but I get the error Index was OutOfRange. I can't find where is the problem.

There is the error:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
>   Parameter name: index
>   at System.Collections.ArrayList.get_Item(Int32 index)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewSelectedRowCollection.get_Item(Int32 index)

My main declarations:

```
private Teams team1, team2;
DataTable tQues = new DataTable(), tAnsw = new DataTable();
List<Question> ques = new List<Question>(); private bool edQues = false; 
private int quesSelected = -1;
List<Answers> answ = new List<Answers>(); private bool edAnsw = false; 
private int answSelected = -1;
```

Class `Question`:

```
public class Question
{
   public static int nextID = 1;
   public int questionID;
   public String text;
   public int maxPoints;
   public int answersCount = 0;
   public int pointsCount = 0;
   public bool played = false;

   public Question()
   {
        this.questionID = nextID++;
   }

   public Question(String text, int maxPoints) 
   {
        this.questionID = nextID++;
        this.text = text;
        this.maxPoints = maxPoints;
   }

   public static void Save(List<Question> list) 
   {
        using (var file = new FileStream("Questions.xml", FileMode.Create)) {
            XmlSerializer xml = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Question>));
            xml.Serialize(file, list);
        }
   }

   public static List<Question> Load() 
   {
        using (var file = new FileStream("Questions.xml", FileMode.Open))
        {
            XmlSerializer xml = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Question>));

            return (List<Question>) xml.Deserialize(file);
        }
   }
}
```

There I load list of objects from file.

```
private void fMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (File.Exists("Questions.xml"))
        {
            ques = Question.Load();
        }

        //add columns to ques
        tQues.Columns.Add("id", typeof(int));
        tQues.Columns.Add("intrebarea", typeof(String));
        tQues.Columns.Add("maxPoints", typeof(int));
        tQues.Columns.Add("played", typeof(String));

        // add columns to answ
        tAnsw.Columns.Add("id", typeof(int));
        tAnsw.Columns.Add("questionid", typeof(int));
        tAnsw.Columns.Add("teamid", typeof(int));
        tAnsw.Columns.Add("text", typeof(String));
        tAnsw.Columns.Add("points", typeof(int));

        //open queries
        OpenQues();
        OpenAnsw();
}
```

There I load objects to grid:

```
private void OpenQues()
{
        tQues.Clear();

        foreach (Question i in ques)
        {
            tQues.Rows.Add(i.questionID, i.text, i.maxPoints, i.played ? "yes" : "no");
        }

        gridQuestions.DataSource = tQues;
        gridQuestions.Columns[0].Visible = false;
}
```

There is where the I have the error(line 70):

```
private void setQuesSelected()
{
        if (gridQuestions.Rows.Count > 0)
            foreach (Question i in ques)
            {
         /*70 line*/if (Convert.ToInt32(gridQuestions.Rows[gridQuestions.SelectedRows[0].Index].Cells[0].Value) == i.questionID)
                {
                    quesSelected = ques.IndexOf(i);
                    break;
                }
            }
        else
            quesSelected = -1;
}
```

Comment: Could you please mark the line 70 with an comment. We can not see the line number.

Comment: Surely `gridQuestions.Rows[gridQuestions.SelectedRows[0].Index]` is equivalent to just `gridQuestions.SelectedRows[0]`. Which is what is failing, because there are no selected rows at the point you're calling this.

Comment: Change to >= 0 : gridQuestions.Rows.Count > 0.  A DGV has -1 rows before columns are added and zero rows after the columns are added.  So settQuesSelected is being called before the rows are added.  You did not provided the code that is calling setQuesSelected.  Normally when this happens an event is being called in the constructor and it is normal for event to run before rows are added to DGV so you must be able to handle the case when rows equal -1 and zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you case `gridQuestions.SelectedRows[0].Index` is equal to -1 or `SelectedRows` is empty because you haven't selected rows

Comment: Why? function setQuesSelected() isn't called in formLoad It is called after I have loaded the objects to grid. So the rowsCount is more than 0 and the quesSelected isn't -1. Or I don't understands something.

Comment: Look up to exception message - DataGridView**SelectedRow**Collection